# how to to force TextView to use the available space using layout_weight?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have these 6 text views in the same `LinearLayout` (the parent layout is a table row layout
and I'm using `layout_weight` to split the screen width between them
the text view isn't respecting the `layout_weight` spacing, causing the last text view to exceed the screen width (when the text views has longer text)

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_equipment_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#4b7940"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />
```

Comment: Remove `android:layout_weight="2"` from TextView, as you added two times.